# A tax on the average and variance

Tags: statistics

This seems simple but why doesn't this work?

"A recent study indicates that the annual cost of maintaining and repairing a car in a town averages 200 with a variance of 260. If a tax of 20% is introduced on all items associated with car repairs, what will be the variance of the annual cost of maintaining and repairing a car?"

The answer in the book is 374.4

How does that work? Why can't I just add on 20% to the variance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is fairly easy. The formula for the variance of a random variable X is:

Var(X) = Sigma((x - mu)^2*P(x).

Now replace x by 1.2x and mu by 1.2mu. The new variance is:

Var(1.2X) = 1.44Var(X)= 1.44*260 = 374.4

Comment: Thank you, but can you clarify your answer a little bit? Where are you getting 1.2?

Comment: @Seraphim: the 1.2 comes from 100% + 20% = 120% = 1.2

Comment: I know I'm asking dumb questions but how does this fit into the equation for variance?

Comment: @Seraphim: Simply because if you increase x by .2x and mu by .2mu, then the overall var(x) is increased by 1.2^2 = 1.44 times.

Comment: Thank you very much! Repped

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just add 10% to the variance because the formula for variance is, in a sense, to complicated. You could only do that if the varience, $V(X)$ had the property that $aV(X)=V(aX)$, where we have defined $aX$ so that the $a$ distributes to each data point. But look at the formula for variance - it's immediately obvious that this is impossible.

Here's a good demonstration if the above isn't convincing: Let $X=\{-1,1\}$. $V(X)=1$. Now consider $V(2X)=V(\{-2,2\})=\frac{1}{2}(4+4)=4$. The point is that the squaring screws things up, as the $2$ turning into a factor of $4$ should indicate. Instead of $aV(X)=V(aX)$ we have that $a^2V(X)=V(aX)$